# Regular expression mathces

Tags: php, regex, match, preg-match

how to match all characters after the string "/src/" in this text:

*/some/dir/and/src/an/other/dir/file.exst*

How to match: ***/src/an/other/dir/file.exst***

Comment: Which language are you using? Different languages use different regex styles.

Comment: python. I did like this: `(\/src)([a-z|A-Z|/|.]+)\w+` and it works, but if you have any other variants please sahre

Comment: use `strpos` and `substr`, really nothing complicated. Or `explode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
/\/src[a-z\/.]+/
```

Tested on online preg-match tester

Comment: Thank you. And how to inverse this expression. I mean how to match anything before ***/src/***?

Comment: `/\/[a-z\/.]+src\//` You will get **/some/dir/and/src/**

Comment: Or you want **/some/dir/and/** only?

Comment: yeah, I want */some/dir/and/* only

Comment: That not possible with the match functions. Match functions will return exact data which matches to the pattern. You can **subtract** or **gsub** the substring `/src/`from match function output string

Comment: `.*(?=/src)` what about this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use capture groups in your regex

**Python Snippet:**

```
import re

test_str = "/some/dir/and/src/an/other/dir/file.exst"

m = re.search(r"^(.*?)(/src/.*)$", test_str)

if m:
    pre_src = m.group(1)
    post_src = m.group(2)
    print ("pre_src : "+pre_src);
    print ("post_src: "+post_src);
```